# Sending uint8_t array as string in HTTP GET request in C

Tags: c, http

I am stumped at the following problem I face.

I am trying to send a GET request with hex values as part of the path ( the server would recognise this and process it accordingly). Currently, I have it as follows for a test:

```
char sendline[500];
sprintf(sendline, "%s%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", path,data, host);
```

where the data variable is currently:

```
uint8_t data[] = "0xAA0xBB0xCC0xDD"
```

resulting in the request: GET path/0xAA0xBB0xCC0xDD/r/nHost: host/r/n/r/n stored in `sendline` as the hex representation of the character.
This works as I am able to send it over UART to the module which connects with the server.

However, the data I am going to receive from another place (the data I have to use in the GET request) is stored as follows: (this could be variable length as well)

```
uint8_t data[] = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD}; //anyting from 0x00 to 0xFF
```

How would I still be able to have the HTTP request stored in the `sendline` variable as above?

Thanks for your time and help.

Much appreciated

EDIT: I believe that if the data is stored as follows:

```
uint8_t data[] = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD}; //anyting from 0x00 to 0xFF
```

That I need to convert it first to ASCII as pointed out by @fpiette.

So just in order to send `data[0]` that would result in 0x30 0x78 0x41 0x41

Therefore, my GET request would have the `/0xAA...`

In essence, my `data` variable will increase by 4: one for the leading zero (0x30), one for the x (0x78) and one each for the A (0x41)

How would I do this for the whole `data` variable? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Please clarify: You talk about formatting a GET request and include data you'll receive in it. Is *receive* related to the response of the request or something else?

Comment: It seems you what to send binary data in a HTTP GET request. You can't. Convert your data to ASCII and use URL encoding for some special characters. Maybe what you need is a POST request? Have a closer look to the [HTTP protocol specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616).

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean that's the data I will receive from somewhere else in that format. I want to convert it to the actual ASCII value so that it displays correctly in my request. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example for you, with all variables correctly defined and initialized:

```
char sendline[500];
char path[] = "ThePath";
char host[] = "host.com";
uint8_t data[] = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD };
char datastring[100];

datastring[0] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++)
    sprintf(datastring + strlen(datastring), "%02.2X", data[i]);

sprintf(sendline, "GET %s/%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", path, datastring, host);
```

Of course, you should make sure that the size of sendline and datastring are big enough.

The data is written as consecutive two character hex digit representation of each data byte. This is correct for an URL, allow 0x00 to 0xFF values and the server will easily revert back to the bytes.

You could also have the data array much larger and partially initialized. Then you need one more variable to specify the actual length instead of using sizeof(data).

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Thank you.